# Reading JSON data (created by PHP) via jQuery Ajax results in "parserror"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, parse-error

I create JSON-data with the following php code:

```
if($res =  $db->query('Select row1 from table1')){
    while($row = $res->fetch_row()){
        $json[] = $row;
    }
}
sort ($json);
$json = json_encode($json);
echo $json;
```

The result is `[["1"],["2"],["3"]]`.
When I try to fetch this data with jquery ajax

```
<div id="output">JSON will be put here</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()   {
    $.ajax({
                url: 'json.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '', 
                error: function(request,error) {
                            alert(error);
                            },
                success: function(data) {
                    var json = data[0];
                    alert(json);
                    $('#output').html(json+", ");
                    }
                });
            });
```

it says: "parseerror".
I searched a lot (here at Stack Overflow), but my jQuery version seem to be right (1.7.2) and reformating the JSON-outpu did not help (I deleted the opening brackets and tried a lot of other things).
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure there's no other output on the page? I'd bet there is.

Comment: `$.parseJSON( data );`

Comment: _"The result is `[["1"],["2"],["3"]]`"_ - How did you determine this?

Comment: I tried parsing that string and it worked. Are you sure that's the string your php CGI is returning? Aren't you missing response headers?

Comment: If I directly access the website with the php code it returns `[["1"],["2"],["3"]]`. But if I then open the page with ajax JSON call it doesn't replace the output div and sends the error message. I was unsure if it's correct JSON sythax but I verified it with JSONLint and learned that php created a JSON array.

Comment: One mistake: The returned error says **parseRerror** not parseerror. Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 2):

Parse the data return in ajax result,

```
var retData= JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: if dataType: 'json' is specified you don't have to.

Comment: i've got errors with it, too. dataType seems to don't take an effect sometime :(

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you get an object before using it:

```
if(typeof data != 'object')
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Sometime it is interpreted as a string and you have to convert it first

Comment: The OP said they get "parseerror". Does that not imply that jQuery has tried to parse the string before calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to push it in an array. Your query is already an array. SO  try to only json_encode() and that alert the data what you get and try to access the data by using data.somevariable( at least that is how I access my json data in the ajax).

Hope it helps

Comment: Could you explain this a little more practically?

Comment: Well the $row data you get from the database ia already an array. I don't see a reason why you should insert it to another array. Then you json_encode($row) and then try to read it back in ajax. First you alert so you see what structure you get. For example in table1 you have a field called name. You will get the name with data.name. I hope i was clear enough

Comment: You are selecting row1 form the database.  if($res =  $db->query('Select row1 from table1')){
    while($row = $res->fetch_row()){
        $json[] = $row; --> don't use this
    }
} Just use $row= $res->fetch_row(); and then json_encode($row); and try to access you data.

Comment: Ok, then I was right. I already tried this but this way I only get the first value of the row `["1"]`.

Comment: Well then check out what does you query return. As far as i know you can access the json data this way -- > data.VARIABLENAME not like you access the array with data[1].

Comment: I used this example http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107 as basis and they resolved it this way.

Comment: From the tutorial you can see that he is selecting only one line. Beacasue he is using data[0] and data[1] which means that you are only getting one line from you database. In addition, he is not inserting it $array = mysql_fetch_row($result); into another array he is immeadiately printing it into json_encode()

Comment: But I need not a single line, I need all entries of one column. I can't see another way, than doing this with an array? I even tried it with a single line `$res = $db->query('Select row1 from table1');$row = $res->fetch_row();$json = json_encode($row);` (this query results in just one single data) but the problem is the same: **parsererror**...

Comment: I just did today an example with a multiple array. It work fine. Please try to console.log(data) not just data[0]. That way you are going to see the structure of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the content type of the response header (you can see this in any modern browser's network console). It needs to be coming back as application/json. Any other type may cause your Javascript to fail. Before echoing the JSON in your PHP file, try adding:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

This will explicitly and correctly set the response content type. Keep in mind, this in contingent upon your return string being valid JSON in the first place, which it seems to be.